# Discriminants of indefinite integral binary quadratic forms admitting 3 or 6 torsion.

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Are there any results known about the discriminants of indefinite integral binary quadratic forms admitting automorphisms of order 3 or 6? It seems reasonable to expect that any  permissible discriminants ought to be quite small and, if so, one would hope that there might be some classical results on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: as far as I know the (integral) automorphism group of an indefinite form, discriminant not a square, is infinite cyclic. 

Comment: Aren't these automorphisms the solutions to the integral Pell equation $u^2+\Delta t^2=1$ where $\Delta$ is the discriminant? So, they are precisely the units in the real quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\Delta})$, hence of the form $\mathbb{Z}\times\{\pm 1\}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the automorphism group becomes clear when one looks at the Conway topograph of a given form.  For an indefinite form not representing 0 the topograph has an infinite periodic river separating the positive and negative values, so there is always an infinite cyclic subgroup of the automorphism group, in addition to the order 2 automorphism $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,-y)$ that acts trivially on the topograph. Some forms have additional order 2 symmetries reflecting across lines perpendicular to the river, giving an infinite dihedral subgroup of the automorphism group. If "anti-automorphisms" that change the sign of the values of a form are allowed as automorphisms, there can also be 180 degree rotational symmetries or glide reflection symmetries. Overall, five of the seven frieze groups are realizable as symmetries of the topograph. The two that aren't realizable involve reflections across the river, which cannot be symmetries of the topograph.

In particular all torsion in the automorphism group is 2-torsion, of order either 2 or 4.

Comment: This is interesting: I wasn't aware of the Conway topograph (I've since hunted down a copy of 'The Sensual Quadratic Form'). Thank you.

Comment: Is there a classification as to which group is realized, and when?

Answer (score 4):

Any non-identity automorphism is either an involution (i.e. period $2$) or of infinite order; in particular periods $3$ and $6$ do not occur.  Proof: the $\bf Z$-automorphism group is contained in the $\bf R$-automorphism group; but over $\bf R$, an indefinite binary form is equivalent with $Q(x,y) = xy$, whose automorphism group consists of the matrices of the form $\bigl({{a \; 0^{\phantom{-1}}} \atop {0 \; a^{-1}}}\!\bigr)$ or $\bigl({{0^{\phantom{-1}} \; a } \atop {a^{-1} \; 0}}\!\bigr)$, of which the latter is always an involution, and the former is of infinite order unless $a=1$ (identity) or $a=-1$ (involution). $\Box$

Comment: Hi, Noam. Do you know a reference for Stanley's question, about "Overall, five of the seven frieze groups are realizable as symmetries of the topograph."

Comment: Sorry, as is often the case my reply to "Do you know a reference for . . ." is no.  Indeed in the present case the point of my posting yet another answer is that the question can be answered without knowing anything about the arithmetic of Pell's equation or the "topography" etc. of indefinite binary forms.

Comment: Thanks. He asked a separate question after posting his comments here, I have been answering there, and may have found what he really wants to hear, not sure yet.

Answer (score 3):

no 3 torsion. see Theorem 6.12.4 on pages 132-133, Binary Quadratic Forms by Buchmann and Vollmer. Or pages 31-34 of Binary Quadratic Forms by Buell.

[image]

Conway's topograph diagrams seem to be part of this question. Most people have never actually drawn one, so here are some links with diagrams. i wrote a bunch of programs to eliminate errors, but still work. I gradually came to realize the importance, in order to save room, of making one drawing for the river and its immediate neighborhood, then making a separate digram for any of the "trees" leaving the river that are of particular interest. In the diagrams below, I am showing how to guarantee that we have all solutions to $x^2 - 5 y^2 = 44.$ I seem to have drawn four tree diagrams, so there were probably four $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ orbits of solutions.

Oh, one big point, that Conway did not emphasize enough, although he surely knew this. If, you include $(x,y)$ coordinates as I drew in dark green, the generator of the $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ automorphism group becomes explicitly visible as a pair of column vectors put side by side, in this case
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
9 & 20 \\
4 & 9
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The inverse matrix of this generator is also visible, on the far left instead of the far right. This business of drawing in "coordinates" is emphasized in Stillwell's book, cleared up some confusion for me. Indeed, I revised Conway's very careful use of $\pm v$ at every turn to show exactly how the automorphism group acts on the coordinates.

see [MARTY WEISSMAN](https://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.wordpress.com/) about upcoming book, big chapter on topograph

http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-sensual-quadratic-form   (Conway)

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387955872             (Stillwell)

[image]

[image]

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/345128#345128

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487051/why-cant-the-alpertron-solve-this-pell-like-equation/487063#487063

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512621/finding-all-solutions-of-the-pell-type-equation-x2-5y2-4/512649#512649

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680972/if-m-n-in-mathbb-z-2-satisfies-3m2m-4n2n-then-m-n-is-a-perfect-square/686351#686351

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765  ::::  69   55

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742181/find-all-integer-solutions-for-the-equation-5x2-y2-4/756972#756972

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822503/positive-integer-n-such-that-2n1-3n1-are-both-perfect-squares/822517#822517

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage/1078979#1078979

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091310/infinitely-many-systems-of-23-consecutive-integers/1093382#1093382

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132187/solve-the-following-equation-for-x-and-y/1132347#1132347  <1,-1,-1>

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132799/finding-integers-of-the-form-3x2-xy-5y2-where-x-and-y-are-integers

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221178/small-integral-representation-as-x2-2y2-in-pells-equation/1221280#1221280

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404023/solving-the-equation-x2-7y2-3-over-integers/1404126#1404126

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599211/solutions-to-diophantine-equations/1600010#1600010

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667323/how-to-prove-that-the-roots-of-this-equation-are-integers/1667380#1667380

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719280/does-the-pell-like-equation-x2-dy2-k-have-a-simple-recursion-like-x2-dy2

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737385/if-d1-is-a-squarefree-integer-show-that-x2-dy2-c-gives-some-bounds-i/1737824#1737824 "seeds"

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772594/find-all-natural-numbers-n-such-that-21n2-20-is-a-perfect-square/1773319#1773319

Comment: There are mistakes in Bachmann and Vollmer's book. For example, the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(f)$ is not just $\langle -1 \rangle \times \langle T \rangle$ as claimed... there are potentially infinitely many $2$-torsion elements. For example, consider $x^2 - 2y^2$. The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ -2 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$ is a non-trivial $2$-torsion automorphism.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao thanks. I use the intersection with $SL_2 \mathbb Z,$ that is determinant $1$ and infinite cyclic, just parametrized by Pell. Is that still true without reservations? Second note, i have posted many Conway topograph diagrams on MSE, maybe I can just put a bunch of links into this answer...

Comment: Yes, that is true and can be proved

Answer (score 1):

There is also the article by M.Uludag, A.Zeytin and M.Durmus [here](http://math.gsu.edu.tr/azeytin/pdfs/bqf.pdf). Theoretically, an indefinite binary quadratic form can be seen as an infinite dessin d'enfant of Grothendieck. It's automorphism group becomes visible in this context.

You can have a look the application InfoMod [here](http://math.gsu.edu.tr/azeytin/infomod/node/3), in development by more or less the same team. The application is also available for android smart phones I guess.

Comment: Could you write a sentnce or two about what does the App do?

Comment: At the moment the app is informative. It tells you the design associated to the integral indefinite binary quadratic form. It also tells you one of the infinite order generator of the automorphism group. You can look at the \c{c}ark to see whether there is a \ZZ/2\ZZ factor.